# how to merge dimensional arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, merge

```
var list1 = [
    {
        id: 'node1',
        children: [
            {
                id: 'node11',
                children: []
            }
        ]
    }
];

var list2 = [
    {
        id: 'node1',
        children: [
            {
                id: 'node13',
                children: []
            }
        ]
    }
];
var resultList = [
    {
        id: 'node1',
        children: [
            {
                id: 'node11',
                children: []
            }, {
                id: 'node13',
                children: []
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

All my arrays are trees,one node can only belong to one parent.
I want to merge list1 with list2 and get the resultList.I tried many ways, recursive callback,string search & replace and so on, but i still couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will merge all levels of the two tree arrays, not just on the upper most level:

```
var list1 = ...
var list2 = ...

var addNode = function(nodeId, array) {
  array.push({id: nodeId, children: []});
};

var placeNodeInTree = function(nodeId, parent, treeList) {
  return treeList.some(function(currentNode){

    // If currentNode has the same id as the node we want to insert, good! Required for root nodes.
    if(currentNode.id === nodeId) {
      return true;  
    }

    // Is currentNode the parent of the node we want to insert?
    if(currentNode.id === parent) {

      // If the element does not exist as child of currentNode, create it
      if(!currentNode.children.some(function(currentChild) {
        return currentChild.id === nodeId;
      })) addNode(nodeId, currentNode.children);

      return true;
    } else {

      // Continue looking further down the tree
      return placeNodeInTree(nodeId, parent, currentNode.children);
    }
  });
};

var mergeInto = function(tree, mergeTarget, parentId) {
  parentId = parentId || undefined;
  tree.forEach(function(node) {

    // If parent has not been found, placeNodeInTree() returns false --> insert as root element
    if(!placeNodeInTree(node.id, parentId, mergeTarget)){
      list1.push({id: node.id, children:[]});
    }

    mergeInto(node.children, mergeTarget, node.id);

  });
};

mergeInto(list2, list1);

document.write('<pre>');
document.write(JSON.stringify(list1, null, 4));
document.write('</pre>');
```

See the code live on JSBin: http://jsbin.com/wikaricita/3/edit?js,output

Note that it this algorithm has a complexity of O(n^2), which means that it will not scale really well. If the trees get very big or performance is a critical issue, you probably want to look into other ways of solving this problem.

Comment: the list3 is the expected result.

Comment: Are your arrays trees? Or can an element have multiple parents? If it is supposed to be a tree, how do you want to handle conflicting definitions between the two arrays you want to merge?

Comment: Yes,the two arrays are trees.What i want to do is merge a new tree array from server to an existing tree array in DOM memory like 'update the displayed tree'.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want it compact by **id**.

```
function getCompactById(arr) { // must have the same id
    var res = [];
    var obj = {};
    obj.id = arr[0][0].id;
    obj.children = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
        obj.children.push(arr[i][0].children[0]);
    }
    res.push(obj);
    return res;
}
```

The array looks like `var arr = [list1, list2];` In the function **create** an **array** and an **object**. The object gets an id and an array. The id is always the same, so we take it from the first array. Go through the array and push all objects `arr[i][0].children[0]`. After the loop push the obj in the array. Return the result array.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hge7yhf7/3/)

Comment: This does not, however, merge the complete tree recursively. It only merges on the first level, everything after that just gets copied.